# Example SQL Server SQL that uses a formula

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a field, call it "score".
Is it possible to write an SQL that takes the value in each "score" field, inputs the value in a formula, then the output from the formula is written to another field.
I have no experience is using formulas in SQL, and I do not know if its possible.
Any basic example, if its doable, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty vague question, but here's the general idea.

> UPDATE MyTable SET FormulaOutput = HomeScore + AwayScore

This "formula" just adds the 2 scores together

I suppose you could also calculate the "spread" like this:

> UPDATE MyTable SET Spread = MAX(HomeScore,AwayScore) - MIN(HomeScore,AwayScore)

Comment: thanks all...didn't know this was possible, i accepted the person with the lowest score, hope that's ok, for all responses were terrific, thanks much

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but almost always you don't want to store the calculated field in the database as that would mean your database is not properly normalized.

Instead calculate the value when you query for it by including an extra derived column in your select statement.

An exception to this is if you need to do a time-consuming calculation, in which case you may want to store the derived value in the database. A good way to do this is to use triggers to update value when one of the inputs change, or else run a procedure on a timed interval to update all the derived values in the entire table.

Comment: Computed columns can be made persistent, and indexed views also are. I'd not use triggers for that to ensure data integrity/consistency.

Comment: It's certainly an option, but you should note that computed columns can only use values in other columns in the same table, and cannot include subqueries. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx I was refering to a 'time-consuming calculation' which in my mind implies *at least* one subquery, possibly more. Did you have some other time-consuming calculation in mind that doesn't require subqueries? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE OrderLine SET
TotalPrice = UnitPrice * Quantity
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) - they're supported in:

- tables
- SELECT statements
- VIEWs

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing it, I'd advise you to compute it in real-time upon query or as [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) or to use an [indexed view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx) if performance is too slow.